# Node JS, NeDB - How make sync return to parent module

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization, nedb

I have func:

```
let isExistByEmail = (email) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        db.count({email: email}, (err, n) => {
            resolve(n > 0);
        });
    }).then(result => {
        return result;
    });
};
```

And if i make console.log inside it -> will be result.
But, because it's operation async result don't return to parent module.
I need to validate , if email is existed return error, but i can't.
I try make setTimeout and try use async await, but no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the next answer: use async-await.

```
async function isEmailExist(email) {
    let count = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.count({email: email}, (err, count) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(count);
        });
    });
    return count > 0;
}
```

And on the call use again await:

```
async function isAccessData(req) {
    let errors = [];

    if (await users.isEmailExist(req.body.email) === true) {
    // doing
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to imply. But from what i understand you wont get the result back. `isExistByEmail('email@email.com')` will return a Promise and not the boolean value that you are expecting. [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) returns a promise rather then the obj/variable

Comment: I understand it, but i can take a result:

`return users.isExistByEmail(req.body.email).then((result) => {
            return result;
        });`

It's will be promise in state peding, and i can take value only if i use setTimeout.

Comment: I need make page (/reg) - validation if it's post request (and after check validation return errors or true);